# "Access to the path denied" error when building project

Tags: c#

I had a working project, but now when I want to build the project, it returns this error:

```
Unknown build error, 'Access to the path 'C:\VisualStudioProjects\BigBank\BigBank\obj\Debug\App.g.i.cs' is denied. Line 8 Position 3.'
```

It seems like this file is in use by something else, but I have no clue what is wrong here. I restarted Visual Studio and also my PC, but with no result. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Did you check the attribute property to see if the file is not set to READ ONLY? http://www.bitbukket.com/uploads/c0658c4b449f6298b554089de9e6722b.png

Comment: @John: Does the utility you are running, have sufficient privileges to access the file ?

Answer (score 2):

Try Deleting Obj folder and Build project again. Once i faced a similar issue and this worked for me.

Comment: Hi every time I am compling I need to delete this obj folder?

Comment: sorry i know its late, but answer is NO. no need to delete it every time.